# Ideas on IM/chat system for social network website

Tags: php, codeigniter, node.js, chat, socket.io

I'm creating a social network website, and I need a IM/chat solution for it.

**The conversations are only one-on-one, with the users being able to chat only with their friends (i.e. Facebook chat - no channels, no rooms ...).**

The website is made in CodeIgniter(PHP) with MySQL database. Probably will be put on VPS (Linux), so I might have control on the environment. Also, it is expected to have more than 100 000 users.

So, I need some ideas about how to make the chat.

My ideas so far:

- Ajax poll on every X seconds (not good solution for website this size)
- Implementing Jabber/XMPP system (I have no info about this, nor is it possible)
- Using 3rd party service (like [Pusher.com](http://pusher.com))
- creating the chat in `Node.js` and `socket.io`, and having it independent from the other part of the website

After some research and reading some answers here on SO

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11362929/928540

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5654487/928540

**I really like to go with the idea of `Node.js` and `socket.io`, so I would like to hear some opinions about it, and maybe some guidance, links, help, tutorial ...**

Answer (score 1):

> Also, it is expected to have more than 100 000 users

I think the question also is how many active users/connections.

> Ajax poll on every X seconds (not good solution for website this size).

True that. This is a bad idea.

> Implementing Jabber/XMPP system (I have no info about this, nor is it possible)

Something like [Ejabberd](http://www.ejabberd.im/) with [BOSH](http://anders.conbere.org/blog/2011/05/03/get_xmpp_-_bosh_working_with_ejabberd_firefox_and_strophe/) is pretty popular. I played with prosody because it is very easy to install and [strophe.js](http://strophe.im/strophejs/) as BOSH client(javascript in browser).

> Using 3rd party service (like Pusher.com)

The easiest to implement(no scaling problems), but could get expensive. 5000 simultaneous connections will cost you 199 dollar per month(too expensive) which I think you might need? Then again you have about 5000 active connections so it is profitable(?).

> creating the chat in Node.js and socket.io, and having it independent
>   from the other part of the website

Very popular solution, but right now I believe some users are experiencing memory leaks(but this might have been solved). It might be only problem with [websockets transport](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/issues/880). Also it might not really be a leak, but just [high memory usage because of lazy GC](https://github.com/einaros/ws/issues/43#issuecomment-6326908).  I would advice to profile before fully commiting.

Answer (score 0):

[Meteor](http://meteor.com) might be a solution you could use. It's designed to create "live" applications and I bet building a one-on-one messaging system is a breeze.

I know it isn't PHP, but you mentioned using Node.js and I figured if you could use Node.js then you could use this.